# how to use a row query result as a link and then make a new page based upon that result

Tags: php, forms, session, search, cookies

This is my PHP file that returns the forms search results:

```
<table style="padding:3px;text-align:center;text-color:#817679;" width="825px">

<tr class="tborder">

<td width="150px" class="blockhead"><b>Level</b></td>
<td width="225px" class="blockhead"><b>Monster Name</b></td>
<td width="150px" class="blockhead"><b>Race</b></td>
<td width="150px" class="blockhead"><b>Ratio</b></td>
<td width="150px" class="blockhead"><b>HP</b></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("energized");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from bestiary where name like '%$term%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

echo '  <tr class="tborder2">
    <td width"150px">'. $row['name'] .'</td>
    <td width"225px">'. $row['level'] .'</td>
    <td width"150px">'. $row['race'] .'</td>
    <td width"150px">'. $row['ratio'] .'</td>
    <td width"150px">'. $row['HP'] .'</td>
    </tr>
 ';
}

?>
    </td>

</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

I have a form on my index page which shows all the names in a database row that include the characters searched for so searching for 'fi' would return all names with those characters in that order in it. My problem lies with the search results.

```
<td width"150px">'. $row['name'] .'</td>
```

I want the above result to be a html link to a new page which shows all the rows in that column. at the moment the search query just returns 5 row values for each result. I obviously do not want to show 15 rows of my database for every search result.

So how can I make it so you click on the result 'name' and it will take you to a new page containing all the row info for that 'name'?

I need a link for each 'name' search result. I know it involves carrying over variables from one page to another but I don't know how to do it for all the search results.

Comment: I removed your MySQL password. We don't need it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection as well.

Comment: @Thom how do i protect against injection?

Comment: also need my question answering

Comment: You are inserting what you received from the user directly into MySQL. as a rule, always use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on input. Or switch to PDO, it really is a lot better and handles most of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create URLs:

```
 <a href="page.php?term=<?php echo urlencode($row['name']) ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></a> should do it, given the code you specified.
```

This is setting the GET `term` parameter for your page. You'll have to switch `$_POST['term']` for `$_GET['term']` or `$_REQUEST['term']` though, since you can't populate `$_POST` easily without forms.

Comment: could you expand upon your comment Thom, still not sure about how to get the variables from each search result into the next page, so if (1) is clicked goes to new page with all of (1)'s rows in it. If (23) is clicked it will go to a new page and have all of (23)'s rows in it.

Comment: You already select rows based on the name. With all due respect, you might want to read a book about php before you continue hacking this together.